# Minimization of the Pollution Problem

Tags: analysis, optimization, economics

I study Economic Analysis.I came accross the following minimization problem[image]

I tried to show that M is quasiconcave but i failed.
I tried using the definition of quasiconcavity or using the min characterization or the convexivity of the upper contour sets

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use the pointwise infimum of concave functions property together with the fact that the constraint resembles a cone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $M$ is not quasiconcave. Then there exist two points $(w,m)$ and $(w',m')$ in $\mathbb{R}^n_+\times\mathbb{R}_+$ and a $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that

$$M[\lambda (w,m)+(1-\lambda)(w',m')]<\min \{M(w,m), M(w',m')\}$$

Let $y$ be a solution to the minimization problem when prices and budget are $$(w'',m'')=\lambda (w,m)+(1-\lambda)(w',m').$$
To derive a contradiction it is enough to show that $y$ satisfies the constraints when prices and budget are $(w,m)$ or $(w'm')$. So suppose not, i.e. suppose $w\cdot y>m$ and $w'\cdot y>m'$. But then

$$\lambda w\cdot y+(1-\lambda)w'\cdot y>\lambda m+(1-\lambda)m'$$

which is equivalent to $w''\cdot y>m''$. This contradicts the fact that $y$ is a solution of the minimization problem at $(w'',m'')$.